# To generate pdf for every div in the html using Javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I tried using addHTML function to generate pdf for the particular HTML page but it is generating pdf for only current page and not every div present in the HTML.

This is the code I am using to generate a pdf.

```
generatepdf(){
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.setProperties({
      background:'#fff'
    });
    pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
      pdf.save('vehicleHistory.pdf');
  });

  }
```

Here i could generate pdf for the current displayed page alone and not to the other div's.

Kindly help me in resolving it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can only save one file at a time and there is no interface between browser and OS save dialogs. You either need to find a zip library or manually save each one using user click each time

Comment: Is there any alternate method or function to obtain my result??